# connection error between two devices: ImportError: libmariadb.so.3: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Tags: python, mysql, django, server, raspberry-pi

I have two devices that I use as MySql server and Django server. My system, which works on my development device, becomes inoperable when it switches to other devices. Settings on 192.168.3.60:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'NAME': 'bildirdi_hurmalar',
        'USER': 'gungelir_tirmalar',
        'PASSWORD': 'EhuEhu_1793',
        'HOST': '192.168.3.65',
        'PORT': '3306',
    }
}
```

Apache2 and wsgi on mainside.
Error when I run Migrate or runserver:

```
(env) pi@raspberrypi:~/bilidrdi.com $ python manage.py runserver
Watching for file changes with StatReloader
Exception in thread django-main-thread:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/pi/bilidrdi.com/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/MySQLdb/__init__.py", line 18, in <module>
    from . import _mysql
ImportError: libmariadb.so.3: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/threading.py", line 917, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/threading.py", line 865, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "/home/pi/bilidrdi.com/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 64, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/pi/bilidrdi.com/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 110, in inner_run
    autoreload.raise_last_exception()
  File "/home/pi/bilidrdi.com/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 87, in raise_last_exception
    raise _exception[1]
  File "/home/pi/bilidrdi.com/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 375, in execute
    autoreload.check_errors(django.setup)()
  File "/home/pi/bilidrdi.com/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 64, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/pi/bilidrdi.com/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 24, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "/home/pi/bilidrdi.com/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 114, in populate
    app_config.import_models()
  File "/home/pi/bilidrdi.com/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/apps/config.py", line 301, in import_models
    self.models_module = import_module(models_module_name)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 967, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 677, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 728, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/home/pi/bilidrdi.com/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/models.py", line 3, in <module>
    from django.contrib.auth.base_user import AbstractBaseUser, BaseUserManager
  File "/home/pi/bilidrdi.com/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/base_user.py", line 48, in <module>
    class AbstractBaseUser(models.Model):
  File "/home/pi/bilidrdi.com/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 122, in __new__
    new_class.add_to_class('_meta', Options(meta, app_label))
  File "/home/pi/bilidrdi.com/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 326, in add_to_class
    value.contribute_to_class(cls, name)
  File "/home/pi/bilidrdi.com/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/options.py", line 207, in contribute_to_class
    self.db_table = truncate_name(self.db_table, connection.ops.max_name_length())
  File "/home/pi/bilidrdi.com/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/utils/connection.py", line 15, in __getattr__
    return getattr(self._connections[self._alias], item)
  File "/home/pi/bilidrdi.com/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/utils/connection.py", line 62, in __getitem__
    conn = self.create_connection(alias)
  File "/home/pi/bilidrdi.com/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 204, in create_connection
    backend = load_backend(db['ENGINE'])
  File "/home/pi/bilidrdi.com/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 111, in load_backend
    return import_module('%s.base' % backend_name)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "/home/pi/bilidrdi.com/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/mysql/base.py", line 15, in <module>
    import MySQLdb as Database
  File "/home/pi/bilidrdi.com/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/MySQLdb/__init__.py", line 24, in <module>
    version_info, _mysql.version_info, _mysql.__file__
NameError: name '_mysql' is not defined
```

Requirements:

```
asgiref==3.4.1
Django==3.2.5 
django-bootstrap-form==3.4
django-post-office==3.5.3 
jsonfield==3.1.0 
mysql-client==0.0.1
mysqlclient==2.0.3 
nano==0.10.0 
Pillow==8.3.1 
pkg-resources==0.0.0
pytz==2021.1 
sqlparse==0.4.1 
typing-extensions==3.10.0.0
```

`192.1683.65` is dedicated server on debian.

Comment: have any idea???

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to install libmariadbclient-dev:

```
sudo apt install libmariadbclient-dev
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: I had the same problem as the OP and ilzaran's solution worked (kind of).  Trying his solution, I got an error message saying to install these instead of libmariadbclient-dev:  sudo apt install libmariadb-dev-compat libmariadb-dev (I'm running Bullseye, FWIW)

Answer (score 2):

`limbariadbclient-dev` does not exist to my mind. I had the same problem and

`sudo apt-get install -y libmariadb-dev` worked.

Answer (score 2):

`sudo apt-get install -y libmariadb-dev` should be the accepted answer.

`libmariadbclient-dev` is deprecated and refers to an empty package : https://packages.debian.org/buster/libmariadbclient-dev